# Bootstrap modal not filling up space properly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is more of a general question than anything. So I have two situations. One where I create an iframe inside the modal and the other, I fill the modal via an Ajax call.

The problem with the first situation is that the iframe is very small compared to the overall modal, filling up only the left side of the modal.

[image: small iframe]

The problem with the other method is that it may sometime create lots of empty white spaces.

[image: white space]

I was wondering how to get around these two issues. I've tried overriding it with `max-width: 100%; width: auto; height: auto` but they didn't do anything besides stretch it to max by default.

Bonus:
I find that Bootstrap modals are too convoluted to be used in a more complex manner. If anyone could recommend me a better modal system that would be great. I've used jQueryMobile before and their modals were excellent (as they fixed the spacing issues), however they came with problems of their own.

Comment: the width of the popup should consider based on the text. is that what you need?

Comment: @CharantejGolla Basically, yes. There's too much white space for the non-iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed CSS Properties to make this happen as the popup with consider based on the content inside the body.

```css
.modal-dialog{max-width:800px; width:auto !important; display:table}
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Modal with limited text 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch Modal
</button>

<br><br><br>
Modal with Large Content
<!-- Large modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bs-example-modal-lg">Launch Modal</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Tight pants next level keffiyeh you probably haven't heard of them. Photo booth beard raw denim letterpress vegan messenger bag stumptown. Farm-to-table seitan, mcsweeney's fixie sustainable quinoa 8-bit american apparel have a terry richardson vinyl chambray. Beard stumptown, cardigans banh mi lomo thundercats. Tofu biodiesel williamsburg marfa, four loko mcsweeney's cleanse vegan chambray. A really ironic artisan whatever keytar, scenester farm-to-table banksy Austin twitter handle freegan cred raw denim single-origin coffee viral.Tight pants next level keffiyeh you probably haven't heard of them. Photo booth beard raw denim letterpress vegan messenger bag stumptown. Farm-to-table seitan, mcsweeney's fixie sustainable quinoa 8-bit american apparel have a terry richardson vinyl chambray. Beard stumptown, cardigans banh mi lomo thundercats. Tofu biodiesel williamsburg marfa, four loko mcsweeney's cleanse vegan chambray. A really ironic artisan whatever keytar, scenester farm-to-table banksy Austin twitter handle freegan cred raw denim single-origin coffee viral.Tight pants next level keffiyeh you probably haven't heard of them. Photo booth beard raw denim letterpress vegan messenger bag stumptown. Farm-to-table seitan, mcsweeney's fixie sustainable quinoa 8-bit american apparel have a terry richardson vinyl chambray. Beard stumptown, cardigans banh mi lomo thundercats. Tofu biodiesel williamsburg marfa, four loko mcsweeney's cleanse vegan chambray. A really ironic artisan whatever keytar, scenester farm-to-table banksy Austin twitter handle freegan cred raw denim single-origin coffee viral.Tight pants next level keffiyeh you probably haven't heard of them. Photo booth beard raw denim letterpress vegan messenger bag stumptown. Farm-to-table seitan, mcsweeney's fixie sustainable quinoa 8-bit american apparel have a terry richardson vinyl chambray. Beard stumptown, cardigans banh mi lomo thundercats. Tofu biodiesel williamsburg marfa, four loko mcsweeney's cleanse vegan chambray. A really ironic artisan whatever keytar, scenester farm-to-table banksy Austin twitter handle freegan cred raw denim single-origin coffee viral.
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="gridSystemModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="gridSystemModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Tight pants next level keffiyeh you.
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 1):

try setting a `max-width` with a `width: 100%;` on the iframe and use the bootstrap modal size class on the modal.

e.g. [`modal-lg`](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)

Comment: That made the iframe fit, thanks. Any idea how to make the modal fit the screen better? It's still the same size.

Comment: I prefer something a bit more automatic like jQueryMobile's modals. I might take another look at them.